# Simple CASE Usage

Tags: oracle, case

Given:

## TABLE test

```
x  y
a  1
b  2
```

## TABLE test3

```
x  y
a  1
b  3
```

I wrote a query to retrieve all values from `test`, choosing the row with the higher `y` value.

```
select t1.x,
  CASE WHEN (EXISTS (select 1 from test2 t2 where t2.y > t1.y))
        THEN t2.y
       ELSE t1.y
  END as x
  from test t1
  LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.x=t2.x
```

output:

```
x  y
a  1
b  3
```

This query seems correct to me, but I'm not convinced.

Is this the right way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your query does have an error.  The sub-query you are using for the EXIST is will always return true (or almost always), since you aren't lining it up on the "x" value.

As a side benefit, since it's not doing a sub-query it should perform faster as well.

Try this one:

```
 SELECT t1.x
    , CASE WHEN t2.y > t1.y THEN t2.y
            ELSE t1.y
            END AS y
 FROM test AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 AS t2 ON t2.x = t1.x
```